# "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header" error in Flask POST request [CORS]

Tags: flask, cors, flask-cors

I'm getting the following CORS error making a POST request to a flask server from an angular app:

`No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Flask server:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask.ext.cors import CORS
app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app)

@app.route('/testPost', methods=['POST'])
def testPost():
  phone = request.values.get('phone')  
  return phone

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(debug=True)
```

I've tried combinations of different response headers with no luck. The pre-flight OPTIONS request returns 200 ok with the following headers

Response:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Allow: POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:7000
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: accept, content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: DELETE, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PATCH, POST, PUT
Content-Length: 0
Server: Werkzeug/0.11.3 Python/2.7.11
Date: Wed, 18 May 2016 00:58:10 GMT
```

Request:

```
OPTIONS /testPost HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5000
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:7000
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:7000/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

Answer (score 0):

The error was in my return type of the testPost() method. The method needs to return a json response.

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask.ext.cors import CORS
app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app)

@app.route('/testPost', methods=['POST'])
def testPost():
  phone = request.json['phone']
  return phone

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(debug=True)
```